# How to show a blinking cursor when textfield is enable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am working on the project where pressing edit button enables Textfield. Now, I want that user will now that textfield is enabled by showing a blinking cursor. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour?

Comment: No, when you click on TextField then it shows cursor. Cursor does not show when you enable TextField by button.

Comment: Ah now I understand. You need to focus the textfield then. I will write an answer

Comment: and what do you mean by "enable by button"? what's the code of buttons `onPressed`?

Comment: @pskink. I mean by default TextField is disabled but on button click, you enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To focus a `TextField` you can give it a `FocusNode` and request focus on that. An example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool textFieldEnabled = false;
  late FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setTextFieldEnabled() {
    setState(() {
      textFieldEnabled = true;
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      myFocusNode.requestFocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      TextButton(onPressed: setTextFieldEnabled, child: const Text('enable')),
      TextField(enabled: textFieldEnabled, focusNode: myFocusNode)
    ]));
  }
}
```

Note, at first I though you could just call `myFocusNode.requestFocus();` after changing `textFieldEnabled`, but that didn't seem to work. Putting it in a `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` seemed to solve that.